# Why would a program silently fail?

Tags: java, logging, error-handling

I have a legacy java app written up by a previous developer.  A bug has recently been found in it, and I've been given the task of fixing it.

Part of the problem is that there were never any error messages reporting from it.

By putting in a lot of logging messages, I finally narrowed it down to a specific line in the code - it's trying to run a method on a null object.

This is something that SHOULD have thrown an error into the log.  Yet it hasn't.  And even fixing this one, there's a lot of this problem in the code - assuming something will have a value when it doesn't.  Every time I put in a data-verification for one, it fails somewhere shortly down the line for a very similar reason, and then I have to go through the hassle of putting in logging commands every other line again to finally narrow it down.

Why would a java program be silently failing instead of throwing errors?  I can't seem to find any sort of setting suggesting that this is on purpose, but I'm really not even sure where to look for such a thing.

Comment: Could be a `catch (Exception e)` hidden somewhere that swallows all the exceptions?

Comment: "SHOULD have thrown an error into the log," logging doesn't just happen by default, things are only logged if you log them. I agree with @user3580294, it does sound like it is probably swallowing all exceptions somewhere.

Comment: Whenever I don't specifically catch all exceptions, I get stuff like 'uncaught null exception' that ends up getting logged.  This is ... bad?  Not supposed to happen?

Comment: @WolfmanJoe You shouldn't have uncaught exceptions. If it travels all the way up to main, your application is going to crash. You don't want crashes. Handle errors nicely, and log what happened.

Comment: I thought you wanted exceptions to be logged instead of being swallowed? Better yet, put your logging code into the `catch` block?

Comment: When I code for my own stuff, I try to log as many potential error situations as I can think of.  But there's always 'that thing you didn't think of'.  And that's when I get the unexpected messages into the log.  This is legacy code, but it's not doing unexpected messages.  However!  The 'catch( Exception e ){}' thing is definitely a possibility.  Ran a search and those are all OVER the place.

Comment: Try taking those out for a start, or replace the too-general `Exception` with a specific exception. Alternatively, insert a logging statement inside each catch block.